# USB event handling

Tags: c++, c, events, event-handling, usb

I wish to do event handling in C/C++ monitoring USB activity-insertion and removal in Linux.Can you suggest me some resources where I can learn the same?

Comment: Surprisingly, there has been a similar question earlier with 4 votes, and no accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947267/how-to-detect-usb-device-disconnect-under-linux-qt-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

- [libusb](http://libusb.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libusb/trunk/libusb/usbpp.cpp?view=markup&pathrev=599) - to scan the USB devices
- [libudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/libudev-udev-monitor.html) - to monitor devices
- or [add a rule to udev](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to monitor insertion/removal of devices
- Work with USB HID programming
- <strike>Or use the [HAL Daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hald)</strike>   ( ed: it seems this one is now an zombie, see:comments )

Comment: well I am doing this for an embedded system which supports only standard C library which triggers an event as soon as a removable drive is detected.Thus,I had to use usb.h not libusb or any other open source library.Actually I am just a student doing internship in a reputed company but having no idea about event handling.Anyway thanks for the links.

Comment: Don't use HAL, it's officially dead; some distribution still have it roaming the system as a zombie (not the process state).

Comment: well going through all the links, writing udev rules seems to be the best solution.Do you have any idea on how to combine a script and C executable prpogram?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8093 - A small overview about the linux USB system.

A library to communicate with the USB devices: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by analysing [libudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/).