# Is there a Qt solution for detecting USB events (insertion and removal)?

Tags: c++, qt, usb

As some other people already asked here some years ago, I want to be able to detect in a Qt application when a pendrive/datatraveler is plugged and when it is unplugged in my system (both in Linux Ubuntu and Embedded Linux).

I searched in SO and I noticed that most answers not only were very outdated (from 2010 for example), but all solutions somehow involved "non-Qt solutions" to these problem: either platform specific or usage of external libraries such as udev and DBus.

What I want to know first of all is if there is a specific Qt solution for this, i.e. a way to do this without requiring adding external libs or platform specific codes, and how could I use it. Preferentially it should already be available in Qt 4.8. If there is no Qt solution, then a Qt-based library would be acceptable.

Add: Search results:

- [USB Programming with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450160/usb-programming-with-qt): Suggests libusb and WinUSB API
- [Detecting USB notification in Qt on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043096/detecting-usb-notification-in-qt-on-windows): Windows only
- [How do I detect usb drive insertion in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190542/how-do-i-detect-usb-drive-insertion-in-linux): Suggests libudev
- [How to get USB notifications under linux / Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416465/how-to-get-usb-notifications-under-linux-qt): Suggests DBus
- [How to know when a new USB storage device is connected in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852752/how-to-know-when-a-new-usb-storage-device-is-connected-in-qt): Windows only
- [How to detect USB device disconnect under Linux/Qt/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947267/how-to-detect-usb-device-disconnect-under-linux-qt-c): Linux only, suggests HAL, DeviceKit and udev
- [Is there a C++ cross platform USB library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917085/is-there-a-c-cross-platform-usb-library): Suggests libusbx

Comment: Nothing about USB in Qt.

Comment: @Bowdzone I tested the qdevicewatcher you linked and it works great. Could you please write an answer to my question so I may accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already pointed out, Qt itself does not provide such a module. There is however a user-made class called `QDeviceWatcher`. I have no experience with it personally and it is not updated regularly but you could give it a try.

You can find the forum post [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/9382/qdevicewatcher-make-hotplug-detection-easy) and the git repository [here](https://github.com/wang-bin/qdevicewatcher).

Answer (score 6):

No such API in Qt, but you can go on with some platform-wise implementations of [libusb](https://libusb.info/), which is quite awesome.

Comment: libusb is a relevant solution for dectecting USB event only for Linux, indeed hotplug events are not supported on Windows

Answer (score 4):

Just one more tip:

> libusbx was a fork of libusb, a library that provides generic access to USB devices.
> As of 2014.01.26, this project has been fully merged back into libusb and is being discontinued.
> Since there will be no further releases of libusbx, you are strongly encouraged to switch to using libusb.         -----from https://web.archive.org/web/20150519101032/http://libusbx.org/