# What is the interface I have to inspect for detecting connected USB?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, dbus, udisks

I'm trying to detect that a USB device was plugged or removed from within a qt programm via the method: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdbusconnection.html#connect

My current code of the corresponding class looks like this:

```
#include "usbhandler.h"
#include <QDebug>

USBHandler::USBHandler()
{
    QDBusConnection *bus;
    bool success;

    bus = new QDBusConnection("DeviceAdded");

    if (bus == NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << "Allocation Error";
        return;
    }

    if (!QDBusConnection::systemBus().isConnected())
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot connect to system bus";
    }

    success = QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(
                "org.freedesktop.UDisks",
                "/org/freedesktop/UDisks",
                "org.freedesktop.UDisks",
                "DeviceAdded",
            this, SLOT(deviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)));

    if (success != true)
    {
        qDebug() << "Unsuccesfully connected!";
        delete bus;
        return;
    }
}

void USBHandler::deviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath dev)
{
  qDebug() << "device added!"<<dev.path();
}
```

When I'm running `solid-hardware listen` I get when plugging / unplugging, the following notifications:

```
Device Added:
udi = '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb'
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1" has new interfaces:     ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition") 

Device Added:
udi = '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1'
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block") 

Device Removed:
udi = '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1'
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block") 

Device Removed:
udi = '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb'
```

So I was sure that the system notifys the USB stickAnd I'm now allready playing around for hours with the for the usb named interfaces but I can't get any success for my apllication reacting on pluggining/unplugging the stick.

So what Am I doing wrong?
What should be the interface and name paramter of `connect()` be like?
And can you explain me what exactly they do?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `QDbusConnection` interface but you could take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414329/is-there-a-qt-solution-for-detecting-usb-events-insertion-and-removal/31446153#31446153)

Comment: @Bowdzone: The target system would be an embedded system, not sure that project would be implemntable on that platform.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Device Added:
> udi = '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb'
> "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1" has new interfaces:
> ```

I am not sure it is your problem, but the *udi* contains *UDisks2*, not *UDisks*. I suggest you adjust your call to `connect()`. Something like this:

```
success = QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(
            "org.freedesktop.UDisks",
            "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2",
            "org.freedesktop.UDisks2",
            [...]);
```

Comment: I tryed both allready, with UDisks2 and without the number. I just added the code ofter I discarded that trys againg. and my problem is sadly the "like this" as I have no clou how it exact should be, but anyway. I'm gonna give now your snippet a chance. I'll report in some minutes.

Comment: Nope, it still isn't recognizing the plugin.

Comment: Did you kept the service as "org.freedesktop.UDisks" (not Udisks2)?

Comment: @ Christophe Vu-Brugier: yes

Comment: One should to implement ObjectManager interface.