# How to monitor if new serial port was added

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I feel this must have been asked before but the search didn't turn up anything...

What is the best approach to monitor when new serial ports become available?

Whatever operation you do on the serial port the 1st step usually is to select *which* port you want to work with. I'd like to keep the application open and notify the user that a new serial port was added (i.e. populate the list of ports on-the-fly). Is there a better way than running a thread which gets all ports every few seconds and then compares that collection against the previous state? I can of course provide a kind of "Reload" action to the GUI but the application doing that automatically would be a lot better.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414329/is-there-a-qt-solution-for-detecting-usb-events-insertion-and-removal  
I've only done this in C++ and I haven't seen any way to achieve this directly in stock QT.